# Google Apps script overflow when created using GUI builder

Tags: overflow, google-apps-script

I created this GUI https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B27WaIUHQGy0UUFwS2dMS2pMUGs using google apps script GUI builder.
But when running it on firefox it was totally crap. Flow panel behaves like a horizontal panel. But thats O.K. I can use chromium. But in both browsers only part of GUI shows. What can I do? Please give me suggestions to look for.This is what it looks when running.
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B27WaIUHQGy0Y295VzRpYk91a3M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a 'master panel'(absolute panel) to hold all the other widgets on it and that will fix the Ui window size when rendered. It will be useful anyway to collect data in your callbackElement.  Well, at least that is how I do it when I use the GUI builder.
Another option would be to use `app.setWidth('pixelsize').setHeigth('pixelsize')` with the right size.

EDIT : you're right, the absolute panel doesn't solve it... but the `setWidth()` does... use it like this :

```
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("panel").setWidth('1500').setHeight('600');
  var GUI = app.loadComponent('MyGui')
       app.add(GUI)
```

Comment: I did used absolute panel as you suggested. But didn't work. Since I'm using GUI builder I cant set width or height right? How ever I saw on web someone asked to make gui with direct code not with GUI builder. What you think? https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B27WaIUHQGy0NmdvQ2Y0a0dPY0U

Comment: The Gui builder is very useful for some complex UI designs that are impossible to get with pure code see [this example](https://docs.google.com/macros/exec?service=AKfycbyc2SWv6JhDgUpXwF7aAARihIE7WPRmrQf6KIOtfQ) to be convinced ;-)

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Sorry cant vote  you up since I'm a newly registered member.

Comment: "impossible to get with pure code" is a little too much don't you think Serge? All GUI designed on the Builder is code in the end. I never use the builder and can write such GUI. But I agree that some GUIs are easier to do on WYSIWYG editors.

Comment: I agree Henrique, impossible is a bit too much :-)  but the time and skill it would need to design this example in pure code in out of comparison don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need setWidth and setHeight to make this work.

Regarding the FlowPanel in Firefox, unfortunately Firefox uses a different set of flow rules than any other browser. For example, it flows its own way for widgets that don't have an explicit width and height set than it does for widgets that do. I'd love to fix this but it's a browser level issue that we can't really overcome. I'd recommend opening the GUI Builder in Firefox to see what you can expect, since the same behavior should be present there too.